# How to create Radio buttons in prefrence activity

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I want to be able to create a radio button in my preference activity, how would you go about making this possible.

Also lets say I have three radio buttons, how can I program the radio buttons (within the preference activity) to preform the task I intended?

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtons are nice style of Button to interact with.

First, declare the Radiogroup block on your activity xml file

1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choice_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choice_yes"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choice_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choice_no" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

2) Then, in your PreferenceActivity, Activity or Fragment (whichever you use), and after setting your content view with **setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);** you can instantiate your radiogroup by doing the following :

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_choice);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId) {
                 case R.id.choice_yes:
                      // button yes was selected. do your work here
                     break;
                 case R.id.choice_no:
                      // button no was selected. do your work here
                     break;
                 default:
                     // default stuff 
                     break;

            }
        }
    });
```

Additionally, and since the **RadioButton** extends Android's basic **Button**, you can also attach a **onClickListener** to it so the action is triggered when you press the button instead of changing the option between yes and no.

Regards,